# passing content to a deleteasync

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api HttpDelete controller method that accepts an array of ids as a parameter. I'm looking to know how to pass an array of ids to the method.

I was trying to pass the ids similar to putasync and postasync, where I could jsonify the ids. DeleteAsync, doesn't appear to accept json content similar to the other web api functions. Below is my HttpDelete controller method:

```
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("delete")]
    public HttpResponseMessage DeleteUsers(int[] ids)
    {
        if (ids != null)
        {
            ...Do stuff
        }

        throw error;
    }
```

I was trying to get to this method using:

```
    var Ids = new[] { 1,2,3 };
    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Ids);
    var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, _mediaType);

    response = HttpClient.DeleteAsync(endpoint,content).Result;
```

So how can I pass a number of ids as an array to this method?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DeleteAsync in VS2012 doesn't appear to allow sending HttpContent, but VS2013 does.  [See MSDN page here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.services.webapi.httpclientextensions.deleteasync(v=vs.120).aspx)

So I've installed VS2013, and then added a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi  in my VS2012 project.

I can now use DeleteAsync along with HttpContent.

Answer (score 0):

[HttpClient.DeleteAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.deleteasync%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) doesn't seem to provide an overload that passes data. Why not use a POST method with an attribute defined route, send the array to that method, and perform the deletion logic inside of that specific POST method?

Something perhaps like this:

```
[Route("api/controller/deleteObjects")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task DeleteObjects([FromBody]IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    // whatever mechanism you're using to delete
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[Route("api/APIController/delete")]
[HttpDelete]

public async Task DeleteObjects([FromUri]int[] ids)
{
    // whatever you want to do
}
```

You can send the ids like parameters from uri. It worked for me.

```
 var Ids = new[] { 1,2,3 };
$.ajax({
    method:'DELETE',
    url: "/api/APIController/delete",
    params: {
       ids : Ids,
    },
    //additions if you need

    success: function(response) {

    },
    error: function(xhr) {

    }
});
```